# angularjs ng-options select from nested json array

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a json defined in my scope like

```
   $scope.People = [  
    {  
          "firstName":"John",
          "lastName":"Doe",
          "Choices":[  
             {  
                "Name":"Dinner",
                "Options":[  
                   {  
                      "Name":"Fish",
                      "ID":1
                   },
                   {  
                      "Name":"Chicken",
                      "ID":2
                   },
                   {  
                      "Name":"Beef",
                      "ID":3
                   }
                ]
             },
             {  
                "Name":"Lunch",
                "Options":[  
                   {  
                      "Name":"Macaroni",
                      "ID":1
                   },
                   {  
                      "Name":"PB&J",
                      "ID":2
                   },
                   {  
                      "Name":"Fish",
                      "ID":3
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {  
          "firstName":"Jane",
          "lastName":"Doe"
       }
    ];
```

Wanted to list all the choices options name (without duplicates) in a single drop down box using angularjs.

The drop options will have the values Fish, Chicken, Beef, Macaroni, PB&J

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SomeController">
     <select ng-model="people.Choices.Name"                 
           ng-options="people.Choices.Name for people in People"></select>
</div>
```

But this is not working.

Any insights is appreciated.

Comment: people != People, also not valid JSON. `Name` and `ID` need quotes. Here is your valid JSON: http://pastie.org/9418572

Comment: Thanks edited it. It was just typo error. people in People means for each entity in People scope.

Comment: You still have an extra `,` after the `]`

Comment: Copied your JSON. Thanks.

Comment: mkay, im working on a fiddle

Comment: which item are you trying to display in the select?

Comment: am trying to display all the options in all choices without any duplicates. Like Fish, Chicken, Beef, Macaroni, PB&J

Comment: so is there a `<select>` for each person?

Comment: Nope. It is cumulative option of all persons.

Answer (score 4):

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat-start="p in people" ng-bind="p.firstName"></option>
<option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="choice in p.choices" ng-bind="choice.name"></option>
</select>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2vj4PK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I'm working this to be better, but something like this?  [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MWX60l?p=preview) It's a start!

```
 <div ng-repeat="people in People">
     <div ng-repeat="choice in people.Choices">
         <select ng-model="choice.SelectedOption"                 
           ng-options="option.Name for option in choice.Options"></select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Revision 2. Now with selections! [Pnkr 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/zr6WHC?p=preview)

Comment: Nope. I want all options in a single drop down box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you'll have to do some preprocessing on the JSON array and filter it that way. This was the easiest method

HTML

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <select ng-model="blah"
            ng-options="opt for opt in options">                
        </select>        
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.options = [];
    $scope.people = [
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "choices": [
          {
            "name": "Dinner",
            "options": [
              {
                "name": "Fish",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "Chicken",
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Beef",
                "id": 3
              }
            ],
            "selectedOption": {
              "name": "Chicken",
              "id": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "Lunch",
            "options": [
              {
                "name": "Macaroni",
                "id": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "PB&J",
                "id": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Fish",
                "id": 3
              }
            ],
            "selectedOption": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe"
      }
    ];
    for (var a = 0; a < $scope.people.length; a++)
    {
        if ($scope.people[a].choices != undefined)
        {
            for (var b = 0; b < $scope.people[a].choices.length; b++)
            {
                for (var c = 0; c < $scope.people[a].choices[b].options.length; c++)
                {
                    var target = $scope.people[a].choices[b].options[c].name;
                    if ($scope.options.indexOf(target) == -1) $scope.options.push(target);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/HX6T3/</kbd>

I also modified some of the uppercase to all lower case. You can change it back if you want.

Comment: This seems to be a round about way. Can't we not do without pre-processing?

Comment: This is what I was running into as well. Since the options list comes from multiple arrays within arrays within arrays you're running into trying to make angular clean up the json for you. The best way would be to have all options defined in one object/array that angular, or anything else, can call from. Then, just assign the choice made to the individual people.choice.dinner.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and found another solution to just display the Names by using `ng-if="false"` or `style="display: none"` and `ng-repeat-start/end`. Based on @user730009's answer.

```
<div ng-repeat="people in People">
<select>
    <option ng-repeat-start="choice in people.Choices" ng-if="false"></option>
    <option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="option in choice.Options" value="{{ option.name }}">{{ option.name }}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This gives us a select box with the following options.

- Fish
- Chichen
- Beef
- etc