# How can i filter the select values in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end.How can I filter the `count and quality` fields, I need `drop down list` for  count values in first search select input and quality values in second search select input, exactly I'm expecting to filter the `count and quality values`...  I thing I have did a mistake in  `ng-options` and `ng-module` ,so if any one knows the solution help to us thanks....[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KF8ZTAq50sCemTn22vSC?p=preview)

**My Html:-**

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default"> 
   <label>Count</label> <select data-ng-model="searchtable.count" id="count"   ng-options="item.count for item in sryarnorder.colorshades" class="form-control"><option value="">All</option></select>
  </div>

<div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default">
   <label>Quality</label>
      <select data-ng-model="searchtable.quality" id="quality" ng-options="item.quality for item in sryarnorder.colorshades" class="form-control"  >
     <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

**ng-options:-**

I thing here I made a mistake that's why drop down list are not showing.

```
ng-options="item.count for item in sryarnorder.colorshades"

ng-options="item.quality for item in sryarnorder.colorshades"
```

**data-ng-module:-**

Please check my ng-module whether I have done perfectly or not.

```
data-ng-model="searchtable.count"

data-ng-model="searchtable.quality"
```

I have created Plunker for reference:-[My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KF8ZTAq50sCemTn22vSC?p=preview)

For example:- if drop down list is `yarn count , carn count ,burn count`.. if I select the `yarn count` that particular transaction only need to display....Please help.

Comment: all you need: when you select 'yarn count' in Count field then quality has only two option 'Home Textiles,Hall Textiles' right ?

Comment: thanks for your comment, Yes if we select the yarn count that particular row need to be display....can you please edit in plunker and give to us...because it's better way to understand....

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KF8ZTAq50sCemTn22vSC?p=preview), the main issue (why no options are rendering in your dropdowns) is that you are referencing `sryarnorder` which doesn't exist yet.  It's later defined within your table/tr, `<tr ng-repeat="sryarnorder in sryarnorders | filter:searchtable">`.  This may be a type.  You may have meant to reference sryarnorders which is defined at the $scope level of your MainCtrl.  You could do:

```
       <select data-ng-model="searchtable.count" id="count" ng-options="item.colorshades[0].count for item in sryarnorders" class="form-control">
         <option value="">All</option>
       </select>
```

and

```
    <select data-ng-model="searchtable.quality" id="quality" ng-options="item.colorshades[0].quality for item in sryarnorders" class="form-control"  >
      <option value="">All</option>
    </select>
```

Which will give you the results you are looking for with the data you've provided.

See [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OgdpAcDP20Fpm0NjjQPL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, the drop down is perfect, but it's not filtering the value, if we select `yarn count` it's not filtering, the table displaying like `Empty or Nill` ,so  can you please help for the same....and update your plunker as well thank you soo much......

Comment: hey hi @ Wake any solution for the above comment?

Answer (score 0):

You need customize you JSON to work with the array inside an array or you should have `ng-repeat` inside `ng-repeat` to achieve that scenario.

**SCRIPT and HTML**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sryarnorders = [
    {
    "_id": "573d7fa0760ba711126d7de5",
    "user": {
      "_id": "5721a378d33c0d6b0bb30416",
      "displayName": "ms ms"
    },
    "__v": 1,
    "colorshades": [{
      "_id": "573d7fc3760ba711126d7de6",
      "quality": "Home Textiles",
      "count": "yarn count"
    },
    {
"_id": "579ef3feba3bac040b583b50",
"color": "56a5b6831746bc1c0b391c7c",
"quality": "Hall Textiles",
"count": "carn count"
}],
    "created": "2016-05-19T08:56:00.997Z",
    "actual_delivery_date": "2016-05-19",
    "ex_india_date": "2016-05-19",
    "ex_factory_date": "2016-05-19",
    "po_delivery_date": "2016-05-19",
    "supplier_name": "Fsa",
    "buyer_name": "e21"
  },
  
  {
    "_id": "56ffc6d5ab97a73d1066b798",
    "user": {
      "_id": "56ff7bece2b9a1d10cd074a3",
      "displayName": "saravana kumar"
    },
    "__v": 1,
    "colorshades": [{
      "_id": "56ffc723ab97a73d1066b799",
      "quality": "Hall Textiles",
      "count": "burn count"
    }],
    "created": "2016-04-02T13:19:17.746Z",
    "actual_delivery_date": "2016-04-02",
    "ex_india_date": "2016-04-04",
    "ex_factory_date": "2016-04-02",
    "po_delivery_date": "2016-04-02",
    "supplier_name": "Fsa",
    "buyer_name": "Binary hand"
  },
  
  {
    "_id": "56ffc5e0ab97a73d1066b796",
    "user": {
      "_id": "56ff7bece2b9a1d10cd074a3",
      "displayName": "saravana kumar"
    },
    "__v": 1,
    "colorshades": [{
      "_id": "56ffc608ab97a73d1066b797",
      "quality": "yarn quality",
      "count": "carn count"
    }],
    "created": "2016-04-02T13:15:12.876Z",
    "ex_india_date": "2016-04-02",
    "ex_factory_date": "2016-04-02",
    "po_delivery_date": "2016-04-02",
    "supplier_name": "Fsa",
    "buyer_name": "e21"
  }];
  
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="com-md-6">
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default"> 
               <label>Count</label> <select ng-model="searchtable.count" id="count" ng-options="items['count'] for items in sryarnorders[0]['colorshades']" class="form-control">
                 <option value="">All</option>
               </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 form-group form-group-default">
            <label>Quality</label>
            <select ng-model="searchtable.quality" id="quality" ng-options="item.quality for item in sryarnorders[0].colorshades" class="form-control"  >
              <option value="">All</option>
            </select>
        
        <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered ">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2"> S.no </th>
            
            <th colspan="2" width="100%"> description </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Po Delivery Date </th>
            <th rowspan="2"> EX Factory date </th>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <th width="20%"> Count </th>
            <th width="20%"> Quality </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="sryarnorder in sryarnorders | filter: searchtable['count']['count'] | filter: searchtable['quality']['count']">
            <td data-title="'S.No'" sortable="'s_no'" filter="{ 's_no': 'text' }">{{$index + 1}}</td>
               
                
                <td data-title="'Count'" sortable="'count'" filter="{ 'count': 'text' }">
                <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #fff;margin-top:13px;" ng-repeat="sryarnorder in sryarnorder.colorshades">{{sryarnorder.count}}
                </div>
                </td>
                <td data-title="'Quality'" sortable="'quality'" filter="{ 'quality': 'text' }">
                <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #fff;margin-top:13px;" ng-repeat="sryarnorder in sryarnorder.colorshades">{{sryarnorder.quality}}
                </div>
                </td>

                
                <td data-title="'Po Delivery Date'" sortable="'po_delivery_date'" filter="{ 'po_delivery_date': 'text' }">{{sryarnorder.po_delivery_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                
                <td data-title="'EX Factory date'" sortable="'ex_factory_date'" filter="{ 'ex_factory_date': 'text' }">{{sryarnorder.ex_factory_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
                
            </tr>
           
        </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey hi thanks for your answer , but why only two transaction  of `count and quality` values displaying in that search select element? ...then why the third transaction of `carn count and yarn quality` is not showing? any idea and solution please......

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam Thats what i told ablove. To achieve `ng-repeat` for array inside an array you have two customize by using it twice or any other way. Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944582/angularjs-ng-options-select-from-nested-json-array